# Questions on the theory of Lasso

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions, statistical-inference

The linear model ${\bf Y}={X\beta}+\epsilon$, where ${\bf Y}$ is a $n\times 1$ vector, and ${\bf X}$ is $n\times p$ matrix. $n\lt p$ and $rank({\bf X})=n$. $\epsilon\sim N(0, \sigma^2)$. How to prove $\|X(X^TX)^{-1}X^TY-Y+\epsilon\|_2^2/\sigma^2$ is $\chi^2_p$-distributed.

I think this statement in $\textit{Statistics for High Dimensional Data: Methods, Theory and Applications}$ by P. Buhlmann and S. Van de Geer is wrong. $\|X(X^TX)^{-1}X^T-Y+\epsilon\|_2^2/\sigma^2$ should be $\chi^2_n$-distributed.

Comment: What is this *High Dimensional Statistics*?

Comment: Sorry. I have written the name of book completely.

Comment: If, by any chance, you are referring to the statement in Sect 6.2.1, it says $p \leq n$, and you have missed a $Y$ in $X (X^T X)^{-1} X^T Y$

Comment: Yes. Thank you! when $p\leq n$, it holds. I didn't notice this. Since in former chapter, we have the reverse condition

Comment: How to show ${\bf V_j}=\epsilon^T{\bf X}^{(j)}/(\sqrt{n\sigma^2})$ is $N(0,1)$-distributed on the bottom of Page 103. Thank you very much!

Comment: I think you should post this as a new question.

Comment: Thank you very much for your patient and kind reply! I figured it out and it's easy.